# The output of a clocked SR-latch with four NAND gates is unexpected

Tags: verilog

Here is my code:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module sr_latch (input s,r,clk ,output q,q_bar,w,w_bar);
    wire i,j;
    assign w=q;
    assign w_bar=q_bar;
    nand#7(i , r , clk);
    nand#7(j , s , clk);
    nand#7(q_bar,q,i);
    nand#7(q , q_bar , j);
endmodule

module tb_sr_latch();
    reg s,r,clk;
    wire q,q_bar,w,w_bar;
    sr_latch op( s , r , clk , q , q_bar ,w,w_bar);
    initial begin 
        clk=1; s=0 ; r=1; 
        #50 r=0;
        #50 s=1;
        #50 r=1;
    end
endmodule
```

I don't know why the output for `s=1` and `r=1` is 1. If I use another testbench (for example adding `q=0` in the beginning), it makes lots of "X" values.

Answer (score 0):

The `q` and `q_bar` outputs are both 1 when both `s` and `r` inputs are 1 because of how the `nand` gates are modeled.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 28.4 *and, nand, nor, or, xor, and xnor gates*.  If both inputs to a `nand` gate are 1, the output will be 0.  If either input is 0, the output is 1.

I added instance names to clarify my explanation:

```
nand #7 n1 (i , r , clk);
nand #7 n2 (j , s , clk);
nand #7 n3 (q_bar , q , i);
nand #7 n4 (q , q_bar , j);
```

Since clk=1, when r=1, the `n1` `nand` gate forces i=0.

Similarly, when s=1, the `n2` `nand` gate forces j=0.

When i=0, the `n3` `nand` gate forces `q_bar` to 1, regardless of `q`.

Similarly, when j=0, the `n4` `nand` gate forces `q` to 1, regardless of `q_bar`.

If that is not the behavior you desire, you need to change your Verilog code to get whatever it is that you want; you did not describe what you want in this case.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe R=S=1 is a valid input to a (gated) SR latch. In that state, any output would be invalid. Truth tables for an SR Latch: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/163164/sr-flip-flop-nor-or-nand

Also see: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/62501/why-is-s-1-r-1-state-forbidden-in-rs-flip-flop?rq=1

Comment: I do know it's not a valid input, but my verilog code doesn't show that! I don't know why.

Comment: The reason it's invalid is that the output isn't valid. That doesn't mean the output will produce an unknown (X), but that the output **cannot** and should not be used, since the result is unpredictable.